# Is there a plugin or any way to automatically graph wiki content pages?

Tags: graph, sitemap, web-crawler, dokuwiki

Having a DokuWiki with some content (regular to small in sice and depth) I would like to automatically generate a GraphViz or Freeplane or any Form of easy to grasp visualisation of my content.

Why? Because the wiki tends to become less and less effective, when searching and organizing its content. As a user I have no good way to get a sharp Idea of the Wiki structure, which is why more and more often topics are not written and found where they supposed to be.

[How to generate graphical sitemap of large website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672532/1370465) is what I found so far, but because my wiki is not that big, it would be quicker for me to just manually make a graph. And because the main topics are not that often updated or extended (like 10 extension a month tops), it would not be that hard to keed it up to date manually.

However, I would like to avoid manual tasks, at least in the future.

So is there a plugin or any other good way to graph the contents?

1. starting on the landing page, following the internal-wiki-links
2. using the [namespace-sitemap](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki?do=index)

Either one would be nice, 1. interest me a bit more, because it reflects the paths a user could go, when just calling the wiki-start-page. I am greatful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple tool to do just that, the graph can then be analyzed in Gephi. Have a look at this blogpost: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-08/02-graphing_dokuwiki_help_needed

Comment: NICE! after some bumbs I got it working - one thing however is not clear to me right now: what is neccessary to have edges? neither dot or gexf format results in a graph with edges for my wiki - although using full depth and having nested namespaces (root/level1/level2/link)